# Flutter The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i was trying to connect my app to firebase realtime database, but got the error
**The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining the operator '[]'**
in line

```
snapshot.data!.snapshot.value?["Temperature:"]
snapshot.data!.snapshot.value?["Humidity:"]
```

more precisely in **["Temperature:"]** and **["Humidity:"].**
my goal is to change the value of temp and hum in firebase and it detect the change in the app.

please let me know if you have any idea how to fix it.

here's my full code

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

class IOTScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const IOTScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _IOTScreenState createState() => _IOTScreenState();
}

class _IOTScreenState extends State<IOTScreen> {
  bool value = false;
  bool values = false;
  final dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initializeFirebase();
  }

  void initializeFirebase() async {
    try {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      print('Firebase initialized successfully');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Failed to initialize Firebase: $e');
    }
  }

  void onUpdate() {
    setState(() {
      value = !value;
    });
  }

  void onUpdate2() {
    setState(() {
      values = !values;
    });
  }

  void writeData() {
    //dbRef.child("Data").set({"Humidity: ": 0, "Temperature: ": 0});
    dbRef.child("LightStates").set({"switch": !value});
  }

  void writeData2() {
    dbRef.child("FanStates").set({"switch": !values});
  }

  @override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown]);
  return Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder(
      stream: dbRef.child("Data").onValue,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData &&
            !snapshot.hasError &&
            snapshot.data?.snapshot.value! != null) {
          return Column(
            children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Icon(Icons.clear_all, size: 30),
                        Text(
                          "Egg Incubator",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Icon(Icons.settings, size: 30)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              "Temperature",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Text(
                              snapshot.data!.snapshot.value?["Temperature:"],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Column(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Humidity",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(
                          snapshot.data!.snapshot.value?.["Humidity:"],
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 60,
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton.extended(
                      onPressed: () {
                        writeData();
                        onUpdate();
                      },
                      label: value ? Text("Lamp ON") : Text("Lamp OFF"),
                      elevation: 20,
                      backgroundColor: value ? Colors.yellow : Colors.white60,
                      icon: value
                          ? Icon(Icons.wb_incandescent)
                          : Icon(Icons.wb_incandescent_outlined)),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 60,
                  ),
                  FloatingActionButton.extended(
                    onPressed: () {
                      onUpdate2();
                      writeData2();
                    },
                    label: values ? Text("Fan OFF") : Text("Fan ON"),
                    elevation: 20,
                    backgroundColor:
                        values ? Colors.white60 : Colors.blueAccent,
                    icon: values
                        ? Icon(Icons.wind_power_rounded)
                        : Icon(Icons.wind_power_outlined),
                  )
                ],
          );
        } else 
         return Container();
      },
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Assuming that it is a `Map`) It can't determine that it is a `Map` so you can't just use `[]`. You can try to write

```
(snapshot.data!.snapshot.value as Map?)?["Temperature:"]
```

Comment: it got this error when i debug "_AssertionError ('package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': Failed assertion: line 394 pos 10: 'data != null': A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.)"

Comment: It must mean the data was null. You could provide a fallback value by writing `(snapshot.data!.snapshot.value as Map?)?["Temperature:"] ?? 'fallback'` for example

Comment: it shows no error sir, but if i try to change the value in firebase, it doenst change in the app

Comment: @NyK well I don't know that much about firebase in general, or about your specific database, but a guess is that it maybe is named `"Temperature"` and not `"Temperature:"`. Maybe try debug what's actually inside your `snapshot.data!.snapshot.value`